# How do I align child table using bootstrap 4+

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table which is inside a parent table.
I need to have it nicely styled so that it stretches over the whole screen horizontally.

Basically, I'd like the width of the inner table to be 100% the screen size no matter the cell number in the row.

**HTML** fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/7Lamvwf1/3/

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>cell10</td>
    <td>cell 11</td>
    <td>cell 11</td>
    <td>cell 11</td>
    <td>cell 11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>Nested 1a</td>
          <td>Nested 2a</td>
          <td>Nested 3a</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: *I'd like the width of the inner table to be 100% the screen size* Why not just alter the markup and place it under the other table ? OR simply use `colspan="100%"`

Comment: by altering the markup I guess you'd remove the inner table tag. If yes, then I don't want that. Otherwise, please, redefine the markup in the answer

Comment: @ZohirSalak the colspan works but would like to avoid it if possible

Comment: that's why i suggested to move the table outside the other one, otherwise i don't think there's another way to span the col across

Comment: @ZohirSalak I'll go with colspan then.

Answer (score 0):

first you should remplace the first **td** in first **tr** with **th** because is in the head the problem here is when you use td or th the second td inside the table child, the cell10 will be the parent of this child table so you should to divide your table  even you use the position absolute on your style css and try to fix the width to 1000 px as example the cell10 will be big automaticlly follow to child table as i'am explain to you so use colspan="100%" on the **td**